# KDE: set ScaleFactor for a given app instance?

Tags: kde, dbus, plasma, qdbus

In KDE there's a setting Scale factor:

[image]

[image]

([image source](http://blog.davidedmundson.co.uk/blog/high_dpi_again))

Once Scale is set this way -- it is found in `~/.config/kdeglobals`:

```
[KScreen]
ScaleFactor=1
ScreenScaleFactors=eDP-1=1;HDMI-1=1;
```

This scale affects all programs which are started *after* it has been set.

I have an app, where I can't find a way to control font size. So I set the scale to 1.4, run that app, and set the scale back to 1. It works, but it is tedious.

If I set the scale to 1.4 thru the dialog above, the only changes I notice are

```
[KScreen]
ScaleFactor=1.4
ScreenScaleFactors=eDP-1=1.4;HDMI-1=1.4;
```

However, if I set these manually (that is using text editor instead of the dialog) -- they don't affect the programs I'm starting. So, obviously, it has to be a call to dbus or something like this.

**Do you happen to know a way to set scale with a CLI call?** I'd call it to set scale to 1.4, start the troubling app, and call it again to set scale back to 1.

**Edit**

Found

```
qdbus org.kde.KScreen
```

using `qdbusviewer`. However, I don't see `setScaleFactor` there.

**Edit 2**

I'm using Kubuntu 17.04, but I guess that this option has been around from about 15.04.

Comment: I think `xrandr ` has been replaced by `kscreen`, I am using probably a different version of Kubuntu, I use 16.04.2. This will make my answer probably pretty useless. Please let me know which version you use, so I can install the same version for further testing and have the chance to edit my answer. Thanks...

Comment: @mook765 See *edit 2*.

Answer (score 2):

I dont know a method to scale only a single window, but you can use the command `xrandr`.

First use the command without options to see the name of the output-device, then use the options `--output` and `--scale`.
Here an example:

```
mook@MookPC:~$ xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1366 x 768, maximum 32767 x 32767
VGA1 connected primary 1366x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 410mm x 230mm
   1366x768      59.79*+
   1024x768      75.08    70.07    60.00  
   832x624       74.55  
   800x600       72.19    75.00    60.32    56.25  
   640x480       75.00    72.81    66.67    60.00  
   720x400       70.08  
VIRTUAL1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)

mook@MookPC:~$ xrandr --output VGA1 --scale 1.4x1.4
mook@MookPC:~$ xrandr --output VGA1 --scale 1.0x1.0
```

A restart is not required.

Comment: Thanks. However it worse than setting KScreen's ScaleFactor because xrandr scales all windows. KScreen method allows to scale a single window -- only I'm looking for a way to do it from CLI.